# How to Authenticate to use the YouTube API from a Cloud Function (Python 3)

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-cloud-functions

I can successfully authenticate with the pattern outlined here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true

for a simple prototype in Google Colab.  However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to authenticate in a Cloud Function as there is no user to complete the flow.  I'm sure it's a standard pattern, however I'm more familiar with the GCP APIs and the googleapiclient is a new one for me.

I have set up service account credentials with the right access, but I'm not even sure whether it makes sense to use these in a Cloud Function (maybe stored on GCS), or whether there is (as I hope) a more elegant solution.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run the Python code in the example you had shared with us inside the Cloud Function?

Answer (score 0):

Not really familiar with Youtube Data API, however based on the API reference for some details you need to issue a call as a video owner (e.g. processingDetails). This means that you need to use [three-legged OAuth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer). For that you can either:

- Setup another function that will generate an authorization URL ->
  present it to the user -> setup another function as redirect_uri to
  obtain authorization code -> exchange it for access and refresh
  tokens -> store refresh token someplace safe where original function
  can fetch it.
- Obtain refresh token outside of Cloud Functions and hardcode it.

Hardcoding credentials is generally not a good practice, hence a better option would be to have a service account make requests on behalf of a user, but this is only possible for GSuite users via [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). With this, after setup, you would use `sub` claim with the email address of the impersonated user. You can see more [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) (make sure to switch to HTTP/REST to understand how JWT is created or, if you're not interested in details, just select Python.